# Put in quickfix list the files whose content does not match a pattern inside it

Tags: quickfix, vimgrep

I would like to put in the quickfix the files **not matching** a pattern. That it, these files don't have any line matching the search pattern.

I know that for finding files whose content match a pattern I may use the `:vimgrep` command, that alongside with `:cnext` or `:cnf` makes the possibility of navigate through the matches.

Comment: I think you could do it with some combination of `:vglobal` and `setqflist()`

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to:

1. use `:args` to populate the arglist with all the files in which you're interested
2. use `search()` to check whether your pattern can be found in each file, and if it does not, add its path to a list
3. give that list to `getqflist()` to transform it into a quickfix list, and invoke `setqflist()` to add it onto the stack of quickfix lists

For example, if you're looking for all the files matching the glob `/etc/*.conf`, but not containing the pattern `network`, you could execute these 3 lines:

```
args /etc/*.conf
let lines = [] | sil argdo if ! search('network', 'nW') | let lines += [expand('%:p')] | endif
call setqflist(getqflist({'lines': lines, 'efm': '%f'}).items) | cw
```

---

To make this easier, you could wrap the code inside a function and call it from a custom Ex command:

```
com -nargs=* Vimgrepv call s:vimgrepv(<q-args>)
fu s:vimgrepv(args) abort
    let usage =<< trim END
        Vimgrepv /some pattern/ file ...
        Vimgrepv pattern file ...
    END
    let pat = '^\(\i\@!.\)\(.\{-}\)\1\s\+\(.*\)'
    let g = [2, 3]
    if match(a:args, pat) == -1
        let pat = '\(\S\+\)\s\+\(.*\)'
        let g = [1, 2]
    endif
    try
        let [pat, files] = matchlist(a:args, pat)[g[0]:g[1]]
    catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E688:/
        echo join(usage, "\n") | return
    endtry
    arglocal | let curbuf = bufnr('%')
    exe 'args '..files
    let lines = []
    sil argdo if ! search(pat, 'nW') | let lines += [expand('%:p')] | endif
    argglobal | exe 'b '..curbuf
    call setqflist(getqflist({'lines': lines, 'efm': '%f'}).items) | cw
    call setqflist([], 'a', {'title': printf('files in %s NOT containing %s', files, pat)})
endfu
```

It installs the custom command `Vimgrepv`, which you could use like this:

```
:Vimgrepv /some pattern/ file ...
```

or like this:

```
:Vimgrepv pattern file ...
```

---

For more info, see:

```
:h :args
:h :argdo
:h search()
:h getqflist()
:h setqflist()
```

Comment: Nice answer. Since answers are intended to be informative and precise, I prefer to see code use the full forms of all commands and functions (ie no abbreviations). I think they have their place interactively, but in maintainable code less-so.

Comment: Always learn something from your answer, didn't know the `arglocal` trick, +1.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using an external tool is much easier in this case.

Let's suppose your `set grepprg=/usr/bin/grep\ -n` is GNU grep (i.e. it supports `grep -L`).

Then

```
:set gfm=%f
:silent grep -L 'pattern' files
:set gfm&
:copen
```

does it. See also `:h :grep`, `:h 'grepprg'` and `:h 'grepformat'`.

If you do this often, you may want to pack it into a user-command.